# Keras different size images

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

UNet,
I have a list of 670 different size RGB images(X_train)
tensorflow backend

```
X_train=[]
img = imread(path  + '/images/' + id_ + '.png')[:,:,:3]
X_train.append(img)
inputs = Input((None, None, 3))
results = model.fit(np.array(X_train), np.array(Y_train),  
                 validation_split=0.1, batch_size=8, epochs=30)
```

> Error when checking input: expected input_14 to have 4 dimensions, but
>   got array with shape (670, 1)

How can i use different size images with keras?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can resize them to a specific size, i.e. the input size of your model.

Comment: yes, but it'll decrease iou, due to double resize(input and output)
and full conv models can work with different size images

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Keras deal with input images with different size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39814777/can-keras-deal-with-input-images-with-different-size)