# Loading image with different input size than training in Keras

Tags: keras

I am working on a CNN that deals with super-resolution. It is required that I extract patches from the image, then train on these small patches (ie.41x41).

However, when it comes to predicting the image, the image is of a larger size than the patches. But Keras doesn't allow me to predict an image of larger size than the training images.

I have read [Can Keras deal with input images with different size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39814777/can-keras-deal-with-input-images-with-different-size). I have tried the way by putting `None` in my network input shape and then loading the weights. However, when it comes to this line: `c1 = PReLU()(c1)`, I get the error: `nt() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'`. The code is attched below.

How can I fix this problem? I am using Keras with tensorflow backend. I have no fully connected layers, all are Conv2D with relu, except for the snippet below, is PReLU for c1.

Thanks.

```
input_shape = (None,None,1)
x = Input(shape = input_shape)
c1 = Convolution2D(64, (3,3), init = 'he_normal', padding='same', name='Conv1')(x)
c1 = PReLU()(c1)
#............................
output_img = keras.layers.add([x, finalconv])
model = Model(x, output_img)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Keras doesn't allow me to predict an image of larger size than the
>   training images

This is wrong, and `keras` allows you to do so when your network is designed properly.

> However, when it comes to this line: c1 = PReLU()(c1), I get the
>   error: nt() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a
>   number, not 'NoneType'.

This error is expected because your input shape contains `None`. Actually, if you previously set `shared_axes=[1,2]` for `PReLU` (default value `shared_axes=None`), you will not see this error.

Therefore, the real issue here is that `PReLU`'s parameters, previously set only for an 41x41 input, but now are asked to work for an arbitrary input size.

The best solution is to train a new model with input shape = `(None,None,3)` directly.

If you don't care about the possible degradation, you can load all layer weights of your pretrained model except for the `PReLU` layer. Then manually compute  appropriate `PReLU` parameters can be shared across `shared_axes =[1,2]`, and use it as the new `PReLU` parameters.

Comment: Hi, @user36624. Thanks for your answer. Hi, so if I keep the input shape as (41,41,1), but change the PReLU input arguments, i.e `input_shape = (41,41,1)` and `c1 = PReLU(shared_axes = [1,2])(c1)`, and re-train the network, would it be OK?

Comment: It should be fine for you to keep `input_shape=(None,None,1)`.