# Keras CNN with varying image sizes

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to use the VOC2012 dataset for training a CNN. For my project, I require B&W data, so I extracted the R components. So far so good. The trouble is that the images are of different sizes, so I can't figure out how to pass it to the model. I compiled my model, and then created my mini-batches of size 32 as below (where `X_train` and `Y_train` are the paths to the files).

```
for x in X_train:
    img = plt.imread(x)
    img = img.reshape(*(img.shape), 1)
    X.append(img)

for y in Y_train:
    img = plt.imread(y)
    img = img.reshape(*(img.shape), 1)
    Y.append(img)

model.train_on_batch(np.array(X), np.array(Y))
```

However, I suspect that because the images are all of different sizes, the numpy array has a shape (32,) rather than (32, height, width, 1) as I'd expect. How do I take care of this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Keras deal with input images with different size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39814777/can-keras-deal-with-input-images-with-different-size)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to some sources, one is indeed able to train at least some architectures with varying input sizes. ([Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-train-Convolutional-Neural-Networks-CNN-with-non-symmetric-images-of-different-sizes), [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/250258/can-a-convolutional-neural-network-take-as-input-images-of-different-sizes))

When it comes to generating an array of arrays varying in size, one might simply use a Python list of NumPy arrays, or an `ndarray` of type `object` to collect all the image data. Then in the training process, the Quora answer mentioned that only batch size 1 can be used, or one might clump several images together based on the sizes. Even padding with zeros could be used to make the images evenly sized, but I can't say much about the validity of that approach.

Best of luck in your research!

#### Example code for illustration:

```
# Generate 10 "images" with different sizes
images = [np.zeros((i+5, i+10)) for i in range(10)]
images = np.array([np.zeros((i+5, i+10)) for i in range(10)])

# Or an empty array to append to
images = np.array([], dtype=object)
```