# How to prepare input with different input sizes for neural network training (keras)?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm building a fully convolutional neural network that inputs and outputs an image. I want my images to be of the different sizes and resizing or adding padding doesn't suit me.

As it was said here: [Can Keras deal with input images with different size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39814777/can-keras-deal-with-input-images-with-different-size), I can build such a model specifying input_shape = (1, None, None), but how should I prepare a dataset that I feed to my network?

I have this function for loading images for fixed image size:

```
def load_images(path):
    all_images = []
    for image_path in sorted(os.listdir(path)):
          img = imread(path + image_path , as_gray=True)
          all_images.append(img)
    return np.array(all_images).reshape(len(all_images),img_size,img_size,1)
```

How should I change it so that 2 dimensions of the output numpy array are not fixed? np.reshape allows only one dimension to be unknown.

Comment: Depends on your model if your model is **fully convolutional** for example (as said in the question), sure no problem. But if you have a Dense/LSTM layer you won't be able to do this.

Comment: Yes, my model contains only convolutional layers, so, I know that it theoretically should be possible. But I don't understand how to correctly pass data to the model.

Comment: What does the distribution of image sizes look like? Can they be generally grouped into large/small or portrait/landscape type categories that could be made to match with minor adjustment, or does it vary widely?

Comment: The variation is pretty small: it's always the square image with size about 50-100 pixels. But it is important for my task to maintain the original image size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure, if this will solve your problem entirely.

So here's my approach and this unfortunately depends on the fact that **you can create batch of data having the same (height width)**. But the height width between batches can change. This is what `image_gen()` is doing.

Then you can directly create a dataset the following way and train your model.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def image_gen():
  for _ in range(100):
    rand = np.random.choice([0,1,2])

    res = [(np.random.normal(size=(5, 256, 256, 3)), np.random.normal(size=(5, 256, 256, 3))),
           (np.random.normal(size=(5, 128, 128, 3)), np.random.normal(size=(5, 128, 128, 3))),
           (np.random.normal(size=(5, 64, 64, 3)), np.random.normal(size=(5, 64, 64, 3)))
           ]
    yield res[rand]

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(image_gen, output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32), output_shapes=([5, None, None, 3],[5, None, None, 3]))

it = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(it.initializer)
  model.fit(dataset)
```

And the model

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models


inp = layers.Input(shape=(None, None, 3))
out = layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), strides=(2,2), padding='same')(inp)
out = layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), strides=(2,2), padding='same')(out)
out = layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, (3,3), strides=(2,2), padding='same')(out)
out = layers.Conv2DTranspose(3, (3,3), strides=(2,2), padding='same')(out)

model = models.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=out)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')
model.summary()
```

Comment: It causes 'AttributeError: 'DatasetV1Adapter' object has no attribute 'ndim''. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Which TF version are you using? I tested with 1.15

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I accidentally imported from keras, not tensorflow.keras. Yes, it works now, thank you